# Update nested object's property in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

My `Redux` state has the following structure:

```
const state = {
 transactions: {
    1: {
       TransactionId: 1, Status: "Pending", Type: "Withdrawal", ClientName: "Paul Carter", Amount: "$28.43"
    },

    2: {
      TransactionId: 2, Status: "Completed", Type: "Refill", ClientName: "Caldwell Reid", Amount: "$45.16"
  },
...
}
```

What is the correct way to update/delete an object from `transactions` given that I have an `id` ?

Here is how I tried to update `Status` property in my `reducer` but it didn't seem to work, my state remains unchanged.

```
const transactionsReducer = (state, action) => {
    case CHANGE_TRANSACTION_STATUS:
      return {
        [state.transactions[action.id].Status]: action.status
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const transactionsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_TRANSACTION_STATUS:
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: {
          ...state.transactions,
          [action.id]: {
            ...state.transactions[action.id],
            Status: action.status
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Also, I personally think, it is better to use small-casing here for property names to avoid mistakes. Example:

```
transactionId: 1, status: "Pending", type: "Withdrawal", clientName...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, it should look something like this :

**if you are getting `transactions` object within `state` directly** :

```
return {
    ...state,
    [action.id]: {
        ...state[action.id] ,
        Status : action.status
    }
}
```

**And if not then**, you need to use this :

```
return {
    ...state,
    transactions : {
        ...state.transactions ,
        [action.id]: {
            ...state.transactions[action.id] ,
            Status : action.status
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

transactions should be an array (it's a collection of entities). 
The 'id' key is redundant, it's already represented by 'TransactionId' (single source of truth).
like this:

```
const state = {
 transactions: [
     {
       TransactionId: 1, Status: "Pending", Type: "Withdrawal", ClientName: "Paul Carter", Amount: "$28.43"
    },

     {
      TransactionId: 2, Status: "Completed", Type: "Refill", ClientName: "Caldwell Reid", Amount: "$45.16"
  },
...
]
```

then you can simply use filter for delete and map for update:

```
return {
    ...state,
    transactions: state.transactions.filter(txn => txn.TransactionId !== action.deletedId)
}
```

Comment: That's what I did initially and it worked perfectly fine. But the task specifically says that I have to introduce a hash map to optimize transaction search. I'm no expert but since we have to copy each level of nesting it hardly looks like optimization to me

Comment: ok, the optimization is never utilized anyway, since you construct a new state object every time the reducer is invoked (return {...state}) - that's how redux works. If you wan't to mutate state, you should do higher level platforms like Java or C++